# How can I create a bool 3D array of char, int, int in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create a bool **3d** array which contains char, int, and int such as

```
Table['a', 0, 5] = false;

Table['b', 1, 4] = true;
```

I created the **2d** but not able to create the **3d**

```
var cells = new bool[word.Length, word.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < word.Length; j++)
  {
     cells[i, j] = false; // what to write here 
  }
}
```

Comment: Need more information - what did you try, what errors did you get?

Comment: I dont have any errors, but I dont know how to create a 3d array

Comment: How about using `Dictionary<char, bool[,]>`?

Comment: I wont be able to get d['a',0,1] for example, can I?

Comment: No, but you will be able to do: d['a'][0, 1]

Comment: thats fine, how will I initialize it? could you please post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary of tuples and bool's, like this:

```
var t = new Dictionary<Tuple<char, int, int>, bool>();

t.Add(Tuple.Create<char, int, int>('a', 0, 5), false);
t.Add(Tuple.Create<char, int, int>('b', 1, 4), true);

// Prints false
Console.WriteLine("a, 0, 5 = {0}", t[Tuple.Create<char, int, int>('a', 0, 5)]);
// Prints true
Console.WriteLine("b, 1, 4 = {0}", t[Tuple.Create<char, int, int>('b', 1, 4)]);
```

Comment: Note that using a ValueTuple with C# 7 support would make it cleaner - or even just calling Tuple.Create.

Comment: thanks a lot @Icemanind, but the var can't be defined as global var, such as public static var, any help with that please?

Comment: @SMH You can replace `var` by `Dictionary<Tuple<char, int, int>, bool>`

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on *3D array*, I suggest something like this:

```
 // ['a'..'z', 0..word.Length - 1, 0..word.Length - 1] bool array 
 // (first index is not zero-based)
 bool[,,]cells = (bool[,,]) Array.CreateInstance(
   typeof(bool),                               // Array items type
   new int[] { 26, word.Length, word.Length }, // Sizes
   new int[] { 'a', 0, 0 });                   // Lower bounds 

 ...

 // Single item addressing
 cells['b', 1, 4] = true;

 ...

 // Loop over all the array's items
 for (int i = cells.GetLowerBound(0); i <= cells.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
   for (int j = cells.GetLowerBound(1); j <= cells.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
     for (int k = cells.GetLowerBound(2); k <= cells.GetUpperBound(2); ++k) { 
       // ... cells[i, j, k] ...
     }
```

It seems that you want to start the first index from `'a'`, not from `0` that's why I've provided that complex call. Please notice, that you don't have to initialize array's items to `false`.

See

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a(v=vs.110).aspx

for details

Comment: thanks a lot, what is the Sizes and the  Lower bounds? for example, in my case the first index should have any alphabetic char and the second and the third indexes should be from zero to the length of the word

Comment: @SMH: *Sizes* are the dimensions lengths: in my (edited) code above you have `26 x word.Length x word.Length` array; *Lower bounds* are where each dimension starts: at `'a'`, at `0` and at `0`; I've assumed "any alphabetic char" means `['a'..'z']` range

Comment: thanks but what if I need to include capital letters as well? so a-z and A-Z as well

Comment: The corresponding size will be `'z' -' A' + 1`, and a dictionary will appear a better solution than array